# Powershell Can't create a list of objects

Tags: c#, powershell

I am trying to create an object of type  Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.SharedAccessAuthorizationRule in Powershell. The Constructor takes a key and list of Rules. Below is the code. I get the following error. 
    Error:

```
New-Object : Cannot find an overload for "SharedAccessAuthorizationRule" and the argument count: "2".
At line:39 char:10
     $Rule = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.SharedAccessAuthori ...
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodException
    FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

Script:

```
cls    
Add-Type -Path "C:\{Your Service Bus dll location}\Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\{Your WindowsAzure.configuration Location}\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration.dll"
$AccessRights =  New-Object -TypeName 'System.Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.AccessRights]' ;

$CanManage = $true;
$CanListen = $true;
$CanSend = $true;

if ($CanManage)
{
    $AccessRights  = $AccessRights + [Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.AccessRights]::Manage;
}

if ($CanListen)
{
    $AccessRights  = $AccessRights + [Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.AccessRights]::Listen;
}

if ($CanSend)
{
    $AccessRights  = $AccessRights + [Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.AccessRights]::Send;
}

$Rule = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.SharedAccessAuthorizationRule -ArgumentList "2", $AccessRights;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    The array needs to be a strongly typed array. 

    Script that worked:
    cls    
    Add-Type -Path "C:\{Your Service Bus dll location}\Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll"
    Add-Type -Path "C:\{Your WindowsAzure.configuration Location}\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration.dll"

    #Strongly Typed Array
    [Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.AccessRights[]]$AccessRights =  
    New-Object -TypeName "System.Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.AccessRights]" ;

    $CanManage = $true;
    $CanListen = $true;
    $CanSend = $true;

        if ($CanManage)
        {
            $AccessRights  +=  [Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.AccessRights]::Manage;
        }

        if ($CanListen)
        {
            $AccessRights  += [Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.AccessRights]::Listen;
        }

        if ($CanSend)
        {

            $AccessRights  += [Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.AccessRights]::Send;
        }    

    $AccessRights;    

        $Rule = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.SharedAccessAuthorizationRule -ArgumentList "2", $AccessRights;

        $Rule;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're ordering of the parameters is wrong because the constructor of the class does take a string and an enumerable. Try the following code and see if that makes any difference

```
$Rule = New-Object Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.SharedAccessAuthorizationRule("2", $AccessRights);
```