# How to create Powershell Object with other Objects as Argument

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, azure-powershell

I am trying to write Powershell script for Azure Service Bus Topic Creation. I have similar code in C# which works but now I want to transform it to Powershell script. But right now I am stuck on how to convert following line to Powershell:

```
AuthorizationRule Ar = new SharedAccessAuthorizationRule("PublisherOwner", "SASKEY++++++++++++++++++++++", new[] { AccessRights.Listen, AccessRights.Send });
```

I am trying it like this, but it isn't working:

```
$PublisherRule = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.SharedAccessAuthorizationRule -ArgumentList "PublisherOwner", $PublisherKey
```

Here is the Error

> New-Object : Cannot find type [Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.SharedAccessAuthorizationRule]: make sure the 
>   assembly containing this type is loaded.
>   At line:1 char:28
>   + $PublisherRule = New-Object <<<<  -TypeName Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.SharedAccessAuthorizationRule -
>   ArgumentList "PublisherOwner", $PublisherKey
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

Comment: Does the PowerShell line return an error? If so you should post it here, If not, you should check what `$PublisherRule` contains after it runs and post the results here

Comment: Edited and added the error

Comment: [This Stackoverflow Post answered my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27480745/powershell-cant-create-a-list-of-objects)

Comment: Awesome - you should post the answer to this question if you get a chance as that may help others who are having this issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Third parameter the array needs to be a strongly typed array. The converted script is as below and it worked:

```
[Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.AccessRights[]]$PublisherRights =  
New-Object -TypeName "System.Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.AccessRights]" ;

$PublisherRights += [Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.AccessRights]::Listen;
$PublisherRights += [Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.AccessRights]::Send;

$Rule = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.SharedAccessAuthorizationRule -ArgumentList "PublisherRule", "SASKEY", $PublisherRights;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the array sub-expression operator `@()` to pass an array as an argument to `-ArgumentList`:

```
$PublisherRule = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.SharedAccessAuthorizationRule -ArgumentList "PublisherOwner", $PublisherKey,@([Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.AccessRights]::Listen,[Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.AccessRights]::Send)
```

Comment: Tried it but it gives following error:

New-Object : Cannot find an overload for "SharedAccessAuthorizationRule" and the argument count: "3".
At line:1 char:18
+ $PublisherRule = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.SharedAcces ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand